2 norm Condition number inequality for non singular matrix
Given a non-singular matrix $ A \in {C}^{n \times n} $,$$ A=(a_1,a_2,..a_n)$$ where $a_k$ is the kth column of $A$. Show that the condition number of $ A $ with respect to the 2-norm satisfies the following inequality:
$$
\kappa_2(A) \ge \frac{\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \|a_{j}\|_2}{\min_{1 \leq k \leq n} \|a_{k}\|_2}
$$
where $\kappa_2(A)$ is the condition number of$ A $ with respect to the 2-norm.
My attempt:
$\kappa_2(A)=||A||_2 ||A^{-1}||_2$
$$||A||_2= \max_{||x||_2=1} ||Ax||_2 \geq ||Ae_j||_2=||a_j|| \hspace{2mm} \forall 1 \leq j \leq n $$
Hence, I get $$||A||_2 \geq \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \|a_{j}\|_2$$
I have trouble finding a bound for $A^{-1}$, I was trying of writing $AA^{-1}=I$ and using submultiplicativity of norms, I get,
$$||A^{-1}||_2 \geq \frac{1}{||A||_2}$$
But this is not helping as $$\frac{1}{||A||_2} \leq \frac{1}{\min_{k}||a_k||_2} $$
Can someone help?

Using the submultiplicativity of norms, we get,
$$ ||A^{-1}||_2 \geq \frac{||A^{-1}y||_2} {||y||_2} $$
Substituting, $y=a_k$, and noting that, $||A^{-1}a_k||_2=||e_k||_2=1$, we get
$$ ||A^{-1}||_2 \geq \frac{1} {||a_k||_2} \hspace{2mm} 1 \leq k \leq n $$
Thus,
$$ ||A^{-1}||_2 \geq \frac{1} {\min ||a_k||_2} \hspace{2mm} $$
Combining both statements, we get the required result.
